Hangifre con Global.asax.cs
En el proyecto en que actualmente estoy trabajando usamos hangfire para poder ejecturar tareas programadas, en segundo plano.
C# .NET FRAMEWORK 4.8
Me sucede que el proyecto, no cuenta con OWIN Startup.cs y quiero buscar la forma de resolver mi problema sin necesidad de recurrir a tal archivo.
Todo archivo Global.asax.cs comienza de la siguiente forma:
`protected void Application_Start(){
    //Configuracion de rutas
    //Configuracion de la base de datos
    //Otras configuraciones
    
    //Hangfire
    HangfireAspNet.Use(GetHangfireServers);

    BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => Configure());

}


private static IEnumerable<IDisposable> GetHangfireServers()
{
        //Configuracion de la DB para hangfire
        //
        //
        var response = new BackgroundJobServer();
        yield return response;
}

public void Configure()
{
       IRecurringJobManager jobManager = new RecurringJobManager(JobStorage.Current, new BackgroundJobFactory());
       //
       //Tareas que se ejecuta...
}

`

Mi consulta es la siguiente: Como puedo hacer para levantar el dashboard de hangfire? Sin recurrir al startup.cs y usando simplemente mi archivo Global.asax.cs
Buscar la forma de poder levantar el dashboard de hangfire sin el startup.cs y si con global.asax.cs.
